# Update a List field in mongodb using Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a class that contains a List as one of the field. How can I update this field.

Found an example for updating a field

```
BasicDBObject newDocument3 = new BasicDBObject().append("$set", new 
    BasicDBObject().append("type", "dedicated server"));

collection.update(new BasicDBObject().append("hosting", "hostA"), newDocument3);
```

From link -> http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/java-mongodb-update-document/

So this is what I have tried

```
BasicDBObject objectUpdateCommand = new BasicDBObject("$push", new 
    BasicDBObject("someList", stringValue));

collection.update(new BasicDBObject().append("id", user.getId()).append("email", 
    user.getEmail()), objectUpdateCommand);
```

Result: No change.

What am I missing?

Tried on shell and it worked [I know its not matching all the ids but it works for test purpose]

```
db.user.update( { Id: 'yourid'}, {$push: { someList: 'appendNewValue'} } )
```

Comment: I was learning how to edit my post and I appreciate you did that for me. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried the same query in mongo shell?

Comment: I have not tried that but I have seen examples of that on shell. Will give it a shot. If there is a success will let you know.

Comment: I tried the shell command and it worked. Updated the main body with the shell command.

Comment: check if the selector part is ok (maybe it's `_id` instead of `id`

Comment: No sure if I score a negative point but my query selection "email" was incorrect. Thanks for asking me to look again. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I have inserted the following rows into the collection.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50bc89ef88555f5ad35da8ba"), "id" : 1, "email" : "test1@test.com", "list" : [ "list1", "list2" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50bc89f788555f5ad35da8bb"), "id" : 2, "email" : "test2@test.com", "list" : [ "list1", "list2" ] }
```

Then by using the following code i am able to update document with id=1.

```
BasicDBObject cmd = new BasicDBObject().append("$push", new  BasicDBObject("list", "list3"));
coll.update(new BasicDBObject().append("id", 1).append("email","test1@test.com"), cmd);
```

After the update rows look like :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50bc89ef88555f5ad35da8ba"), "id" : 2, "email" : "test2@test.com", "list" : [ "list1", "list2" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50bc89f788555f5ad35da8bb"), "email" : "test1@test.com", "id" : 1, "list" : [ "list1", "list2", "list3" ] }
```

Check your code again. It should work with this code.

Comment: Nope. That did not help. Result still the same.

Comment: @parvin both forms you posted are equivalent. The BasicDBObject(String, BasicDBObject) constructor exists for convenience.

Comment: Parvin thanks for your response. I did learn few things and your response validated I was on right track. It seems the field name was incorrect and after fixing it... everything worked smooth.